# Migrating CAB to CAL/PRISM

Tags: prism

I have working on C#.NET project.In this project we follow CAB framework(Win forms). Now we plan to moving CAB to Composite Application Library for WPF. THis migrating process what are the things i have to consider, follow & learn?

Answer (score 1):

### View / GUI

- XAML
- dependency properties
- two-way binding

### Prism and Libraries

- IoC, DI - Unity
- Extension via Component Parts - MEF
- event aggregator

I assume you're already familiar with application architectures that seperate business logic from UI logic, but for XAML applications and Prism in particular the MV-V-M pattern 'marries' the View to the business domain with less cumbersome hoops to jump than CAB.

Note that MEF is supported out of the box (alternative to Unity) with [Prism 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430871%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx), which is very recent.

See Also - [MEF vs. IoC / DI](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1004-net-40-mef-faq-socket-plug-and-extension-.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An excellent MSDN article that contrasts CAB and Prism

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx